# Is $\mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z}$ semisimple as a $\mathbf{Z}$-module?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

> Is $\mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z}$ semisimple as a $\mathbf{Z}$-module?

I feel as though this should be obviously not true, but struggling to show why.

Comment: To start with, what are the simple $\mathbb{Z}$-modules?

Comment: Z-modules are the same as abelian groups, so a simple Z-module is an abelian group which has no non-trivial subgroups @anomaly

Comment: I don't follow how that relates to $Q/Z$, doesn't that just show Q is not simple or semi simple? @G.Sassatelli

Comment: Don't we need a submodule of $Q/Z$? Could we use $\frac{1}{3}Z/Z$ ?@G.Sassatelli

Comment: I just realised the question was about semisemplicity, not semplicity. So my example did not work (it proved that $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ is not simple). Sorry.

Comment: Right, so try to write $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ as the direct sum of such groups. Note that $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is divisible.

Comment: @anomaly What do we mean by divisible?

Comment: Look it up on, say, wikipedia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subgroup 
$$
\{x\in \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}:4x=0\}
$$
is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, which is not semisimple.

Comment: So we know $Z/4Z$ is contained in $Q/Z$, and that $Z/4Z$ is not simple so this implies $Q/Z$ is not semi simple?

Comment: @TheProblem Every submodule of a semisimple module is semisimple. But $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is not a sum of simple modules.

Comment: Thank you, how do we know $Z/4Z$ is not a sum of simple modules?

Comment: @TheProblem You know how to find all subgroups of a cyclic groups, don't you?

Comment: Ah of course! silly me

Answer (score 2):

According to *Bourbaki* (Algebra, ch.8: *Semi-simple Rings and Modules*, §4, n°1, Example 3 (I translate from the French language),

```
Let A  be a PID, P a representative set of extremal elements, M an A-module, 
and for each p in P, let M(p) be the set of * in M such that px=0. 
M is semi-simple if and  only if M is the sum of the M(p)s.
```

In the present case, $(\mathbf Q/\mathbf Z)(p)=\mathbf Z\Bigl(\dfrac1p+\mathbf Z\Bigr) $, and $\mathbf Q/\mathbf Z$ cannot be the sum of these modules – for instance $\dfrac1{p^2}$ cannot be written as the sum of fractions with prime denominators. Hence   $\mathbf Q/\mathbf Z$  is not semi-simple.

Answer (score 1):

No. This would require the existence of an isomorphism $\mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z}\simeq\bigoplus_{i\in I}\mathbf{Z}/p_i\mathbf{Z}$ for some set $I$ and some primes $p_i$. Fixing some $p_i$, the RHS has no elements of order $p_i^2$, whereas the LHS does.

Comment: What element has order $pi^2$ on the LHS ?

Comment: Dear @The Problem, The element $1/p_i^2+\mathbf{Z}$.